# EM algorithm for Blind separation and deconvolution of noisy signals using mixture models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, convolution

I have a question from the paper: *Maximum likelihood for blind separation and deconvolution of noisy signals using mixture models* ([pdf](http://www.ece.rice.edu/~shri/deconv/Moulines.pdf)). In section 2, equations 7, 8, 9 read:

\begin{align}
\pi_{zx}(\theta) &= \int p(z,s|x;\theta) ds   \tag{7}  \\
 &\propto \pi_z\int \phi(x;As,J)\phi(s;\mu_z(\xi,\Gamma_z(\xi)))   \tag{8}  \\
 &\propto \frac{\pi_z}{|\Gamma_z||A'J^{-1}A+\Gamma_z(\xi)^{-1}|}    \tag{9}
\end{align}

Why doesn't the result depend on $x$?